# how to drag and drop of li in list view in jqm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

can we drag and drop of list in query mobile.Actually I am adding list after pressing the button.Can we change the position of row using drag and drop  using query mobile.I am adding like "tc_1" "tc_2"…so on can we change position using drag "tc_2" come up "tc_1"

http://jsfiddle.net/FZQ8D/15/

```
$(function () {



    $('#addTestCase').click(function () {
       createTestCase("dd",true,"null")

    });
        });

function createTestCase(testCaseName,iscreatedFromScript,jsonObject) {

    var id;
    if (typeof ($("#testCaseContainer li:last").attr('id')) == 'undefined') {
        id = "tc_1";
         var index = id.indexOf("_");
        var count = id.substring(index + 1, id.length);
        count = parseInt(count);
          var conunter = count;




    } else {
        id = $("#testCaseContainer li:last").attr('id');
        var index = id.indexOf("_");
        var count = id.substring(index + 1, id.length);
        count = parseInt(count);
          var conunter = count;



        id = id.substring(0, index) + "_" + parseInt(count + 1);
    }
    var html = '<div class="testcaselist_row">' + '<ul>' + '<li id="' + id + '" class="clickTestCaseRow"><a href="#" style="color: #ffffff!important;">' + id + '</a></li>' + '</ul>' + '</div>';
    $('#testCaseContainer').append(html);




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to jQuery UI and use the sortable feature. To make it work with mobile touch, you might want to add **[jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/)**

Then just add sortable to the container:

```
$("#testCaseContainer").sortable({
      stop: function( event, ui ) {

      }
}).disableSelection();
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/FZQ8D/16/)**

Comment: thanks a great answer..can we change position of node..as given in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893698/how-to-change-position-of-node-on-button-click-using-jstree

Comment: if you any idea of this Question please post your answer