# How to change position of node on button click using jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Can you please tell me is there any way to change the position of node on button click.actually I am using jstree in my demo.I read all API 
http://www.jstree.com/api/
I didn't find any way to change the position of node on button click. In my demo "b" node on second position. Can we change the position of node on button click .it ("b" node)will come on "first" and "a" node come on second.

http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/185/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tree').jstree({
        core: {
           check_callback: true
        },
        dnd: {
           check_while_dragging: false
        },
        "plugins": ["dnd"]
     });
});
```

Comment: is there any update of this Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the api, you can use move_node. It seems to require a parent mode, so for your example I have added an overall root node with id="root0". Then on button click:

```
$('#tree').jstree("move_node", "#b", "#root0", 0);
```

This says take node named "b", move it to parent named "root0" and put it at position "0".

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/fuu94/187/)**

Comment: great solution ..but it have two problem 1) it only work when you expand(if you have no idea leave it).but 2 ) is important now if I need to change position of "c" to second and "a" node third position.Let me explain again .first to expand click on "change position" it change the position of "a" node to second.but id i click next change (in given fiddle) now "a" come in third position and "c" come in second http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/188/

Comment: @user3667538, in your demo you called the 3rd node "c-1", not "c". The second move works fine with the correct id; here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/fuu94/190/

Comment: oh sorry but still problem :( ..If you click "next change "position button first then "c" come on second "b" come on third (change their position it is correct).but after that if you click "change position" "b" come on top (fine) but a come on second (why) ? it should come on third ?

Comment: I need to interchange position of node.

Comment: @user3667538, all you are doing is changing the order of the nodes, so if you click the other button first you get A C B (c in second position), when you click the first button, you just move B to the first position and shift all other nodes up one, so you get B A C. That works as designed. You need to make the moves in a correct order, or make all the moves within one button click...

Comment: As you said "all the moves within one button click" can we do both above task on single button get exact result ?

Comment: @user3667538, Because both A and C just shift up one position when B goes to the 0 position. C does not remember the exact position it was moved to, only the new order of nodes. Yes you can make both moves in one button click: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/fuu94/192/

Comment: @user3667538, to move A to the end: $('#tree').jstree("move_node", "#a", "#root0", 3); Using position 2 puts it before the node at position 2 not after the node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54566/discussion-between-user3667538-and-ezanker).